# Google Cloud Storage Authentication Issue with Django using google-auth

Tags: django, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-oauth

I am facing an authentication issue while trying to use Google Cloud Storage with Django. I have set up my Django project to use **google-auth** library for authentication with other Google APIs, but when I try to use Google Cloud Storage, I get the following error:

*This library only supports credentials from google-auth-library-python. See https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ for help on authentication with this library.*

---

#### Steps Taken:

1. I have set up my Django project with the necessary configurations, including installing **google-auth** library.
2. I have defined the **GS_CREDENTIALS** variable in my Django settings to store the path to the service account JSON file.
3. I am using the **storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage** storage backend in Django settings to handle media and static files storage on Google Cloud Storage.

#### Django settings.py

```
GS_CREDENTIALS = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
```

#### Expected Behavior:

I expect the **google-auth** library to handle the authentication with Google Cloud Storage, just as it does with other Google APIs in my Django project.

#### Actual Behavior:

When trying to use Google Cloud Storage, the mentioned error is raised, indicating that the library only supports credentials from **google-auth-library-python**, even though I have **google-auth** installed and working correctly with other APIs.

#### Additional Information:

1. I have verified that google-auth is installed in my environment and up-to-date.
2. The credentials are correctly set for other Google APIs, and they work as expected.
3. I have tried various approaches, including different configurations, but the error persists.

#### System Information:

- Django version: 4.0.6
- Python version: Anaconda Python 3.9.16
- Operating System: MacOS 13.4 M1

---

How can I resolve this authentication issue and use Google Cloud Storage with Django while still using the **google-auth** library for authentication with other Google APIs?

Any insights or guidance on what might be causing this discrepancy in authentication would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I think the error message is misleading you. Double-check the value of `GS_CREDENTIALS`. You mention `and working correctly with other APIs`. What other APIs? Provide more details and the code that is failing along with the exact error message/stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you *may* be mixing up the packages you're working with. `GS_CREDENTIALS` is mentioned in the `django-storages` package, not in the `google-auth` package from what I can see.

If you are indeed using `django-storages`, try to use the setting:
`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')`
in your settings.py file instead of the `GS_CREDENTIALS` setting, I vaguely remember trying that at some point and it not working for me.